# angular.toJson not working correctly (1.0.8)

Tags: angularjs

I am using submitting a payload with angular (1.0.8) and it isn't submitting all my json.  Here is where i boiled the problem down to, angular.toJson().

```
angular.toJson(
  {"yt$location": {
    "$t": "US"
  }
});

// "{"yt$location":{}}"

// I would like it should return
// "{"yt$location":{ "$t": "US" }}"

JSON.stringify({"yt$location": {
  "$t": "US"
}});
// "{"yt$location":{"$t":"US"}}"


angular.toJson({"$t":"what"}); // "{}"
```

Comment: Found some relevant links...
[Issue #65](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/65)
[toJson](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/angular/nVbXhwUnT3Y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs (http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/angular.toJson), `angular.toJson` will ignore any properties beginning with **$**. This happens in a lot of angular methods (like `angular.equals`) because it uses **$** all over the place to prefix any properties it adds to your data.

For example, getting a JSON object from `$http` will add a bunch of extra properties for checking whether the data is resolved etc. `angular.toJson` will then ignore these and serialise your data as you expect.

---

To more answer your question more directly:

`angular.toJson` seems to be working exactly as documented from your example. Try to avoid using data with properties that begin with **$**, if you really have to then try to serialise the objects without using `angular.toJson` and instead use `JSON.toStringify` in browsers that support it.

I think the `$http` methods all accept string payloads as well as objects so you can probably perform the serialisation yourself if this is what you are using. I haven't tested this but the `$http` code transforms object payloads using `toJson` but will pass a string on directly.

Comment: That is directly from the youtube api.  The $ signs often are set as the beginning of property names when there is a conversion from xml to json.  The link i posted above, says it will be fixed in 1.2rc